# How to create a template from Excel to Notepad with exact character positions,in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need to create a notepad based on template/format. 
I am struggling to apply the maximum width with the existing string length and also it is not appending based on my query.
Kindly help me in this.

I have an excel file with a template to write it in Notepad with certain format,

[Notepad Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jthwG.png)

And the Output in notepad is,

[Output in Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l6at.jpg)

Below is the code which I tried and also got help from stack overflow, but I am not able to compose the notepad with the template.

```
Sub Characterpostion()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim CellData As String
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim str As String
Dim cellvalue As String

LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

FilePath = FreeFile
'CellData = ""

Open "C:\Users\Antony\Music\Excel Macros\Text2.txt" For Output As #2

With ActiveSheet
For k = 2 To LastRow
    str = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Cells(k,     
"A").Resize(1, LastCol).Value)), "@#")
    str = Replace(str, "=", vbNullString)

    Print #2, str
Next k

End With

Close #2

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me on this pls

Comment: small correction... in screenshot DOB-Line 2- column 18 -and the length is 8 and the type is Date

Comment: Can anyone try the above scenario pls

Comment: There will be many length checking if you want it to be precise on position using spaces and not tabs. To be flexible, first load the values into memory, then find out the longest text in all the valid range, use that as max width for that column. Then you need to append spaces for shorter text. Please add details/corrections by Editing the post, not in comment.

Comment: Edited the entire post...kindly look into this and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this modified code that matches your requirement. Please try to understand the logic on the rows and cols.

```
Option Explicit

'===[ SOURCE ]===
'#1:FIRST MESSAGE  | Name (start 15, max 20)
'#2:               | Father's Name (start 1, max 15)
'#3:               | DOB (max 8)
'#4:               | Code (max 5)
'#5:               | EndofRecord (max 4)
'===[ DESIRED OUTPUT ]===
'  |         1         2         3
'  |1234567890123456789012345678901234
'#1|FIRST-MESSAGE Name________________
'#2|FATHER-NAME____DOB_____
'#3|CODE_
'#4|EODR

Sub TextDump()
    Const MaxWidthColA As Integer = 15 ' Pre-defined Column A's max width
    Const RowsPerRecord As Integer = 5 ' Each record in source consists of 5 rows
    Dim aValues As Variant, aMaxWidthColB As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long ' rows and cols
    Dim i As Integer ' index of aMaxWidthColB to use
    Dim sLine As String ' Output string

    With ActiveSheet
        ' Ignore row 1
        aValues = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).Value
    End With

    aMaxWidthColB = Array(20, 15, 8, 5, 4)

    ' Dump the output
    Open Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\test.txt" For Output As #1
    sLine = ""
    ' Go through the rows and columns
    For r = 1 To UBound(aValues, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(aValues, 2)
            ' Special case on each 1st row on record
            If r Mod RowsPerRecord = 1 And c = 1 Then
                sLine = sLine & PadText(CStr(aValues(r, c)), MaxWidthColA)
            End If
            ' Pad text if it's not the first col
            If c > 1 Then
                i = (r - 1) Mod RowsPerRecord ' index of max width array to use
                sLine = sLine & PadText(CStr(aValues(r, c)), CInt(aMaxWidthColB(i)))
            End If
        Next c
        ' Only print line then empty the line if it's not 2nd row of record
        If (r Mod RowsPerRecord) <> 2 Then
            Print #1, sLine
            sLine = ""
        End If
    Next r
    Close #1

End Sub

Private Function PadText(Text As String, MaxWidth As Integer) As String
    PadText = Left(Text, MaxWidth) & IIf(Len(Text) < MaxWidth, Space(MaxWidth - Len(Text)), "")
End Function
```

Sample output:
[image: Sample output]

Comment: Can anyone help me on this

Comment: I hope you can understand the maths behind this updated solution for your goal, please delete old irrelevant comments.